# Change the "→" character on backend Orders stock notes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, stock

In woocommerce order stock notes, before and after order qty is separated by → symbol like this:

```
Product xyz 25→22
```

How can i Change the → symbol to another symbol?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following code that will search for " → " character in Order notes content before saving the data.

This order note is added using the `wc_trigger_stock_change_notifications()` function that uses `'&rarr;'` to add the " → " character.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_order_note_data', 'filter_new_order_note_data', 10, 3 );
function filter_new_order_note_data( $data, $args ) {
    $replacement = ' to ';

    $data['comment_content'] = str_replace('&rarr;', $replacement, $data['comment_content']);

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

The order note before *(without this code)*:

[image]

Then changing the order status to pending and back to processing *(with the code)*:

[image] [image]